Is there a way to dynamically parse open API spec (3.0 or higher) in react code?
I used swagger-ui-react to configure the page to automatically display the swagger screen when receiving a spec in json format.
However, in order to provide higher usability, I plan to directly parse the openapi spec and express it as UI using React.
Is there a library that can dynamically parse and extract the path, method, parameters, etc.?
What I've seen is openapi-typescript, which is not appropriate as it is a CLI tool. Is the only way to parse JSON directly?
result example)
const parsed = {
  [path: '/a', method: 'get', parameters: [...]],
  [path: '/b', method: 'post', parameters: [...]],
  ...
}


I think Swagger UI uses https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js as the parser. Either that or https://github.com/swagger-api/apidom. You might also find a suitable parser in this list: https://openapi.tools/#parsers

Redocly has a parser.  www.redocly.com

NPM's got you covered, like always :)
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@apidevtools/swagger-parser
